# Hamburger Menu not working in Android WebView

Tags: android, css, webview, bootstrap-5

I have a weird problem with Andriod WebView. My website's Humberger menu expands and closes fine in my mobile browser but on my Android WebView app when the menu is clicked it's not working (doesn't expand fully to show menu items).

I've already tried the following lines of code from various answers on StackOverFlow:

```
        webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
```

**Mobile Browser Working Correctly:**

[image: Menu expanding correctly]

**Android WebView App Not Working Correctly**

[image: Menu doesn't expand correctly when clicked]

**Here is my Andriod WebView App code:**

```
package com.app.pvm;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private WebView webView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        webView = findViewById(R.id.MyWebView);

        webView.setWebChromeClient(new MyChromeClient());
        webView.setWebViewClient(new BrowserClient());

        WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
        webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        settings.setAllowFileAccess(true);

        webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);

        webView.loadUrl("https://test.app");
    }
}
```

**XML Code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <WebView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/MyWebView"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**BrowserClient Class code:**

```
package com.app.pvm;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.webkit.WebResourceError;
import android.webkit.WebResourceRequest;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

class BrowserClient extends WebViewClient {

    public BrowserClient(){

    }

    @Override
    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceError error) {
        super.onReceivedError(view, request, error);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
    }


}
```

**Note:** I'm using Andriod Studio for the WebView App.

Comment: show your XML and your clients code (and try without `setLoadWithOverviewMode` and/or `setUseWideViewPort`)

Comment: @snachmsm Thanks, just updated the question with XML and Client codes. I've already tried without those two methods but the problem still persists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your `WebView` should fit whole window, use `match_parent`

```
<WebView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/MyWebView"/>
```

`wrap_content` set for height makes this inner dropdown wrongly measured, in the meanwhile whole web content stretches `WebView` to size of its parent (`LinearLayout`) and became scrollable

Comment: Got it. Thank you so much. Working properly now.